# .NET How to get Sql response to string?

Tags: sql, .net

After inserting something into the DB I would like to get the server's response.
For example "x rows effected" or other messages, and put them into a string variable.
How do I implement this in code? C# or VB - doesn't matter to me.
I couldn't find anything specific on this, but I am a n00b @ programming.
Thank you kindly.Could you kindly provide an example for me? Here is my code:

```
    Private Function insertScr(ByVal byte2insert As Byte()) As Boolean

    Dim _con As SqlConnection
    Dim queryStmt As String
    Dim _cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim param As SqlParameter

    Try

        _con = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.DBconnStr)
        queryStmt = "update ErrorLog set screen =  @Content where(ErrorLogID = 2)"
        _cmd = New SqlCommand(queryStmt, _con)
        param = _cmd.Parameters.Add("@Content", SqlDbType.VarBinary)

        param.Value = byte2insert

        _con.Open()
        _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        _con.Close()

        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception

        Return False

    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: I know you're new here. If you want help with your actual code, please **edit** your question and add it. Then highlight the block of code and hit the `{}` button. Code in comments is unreadable

Comment: If you just want to get affected rows count use `affectedRowsCount = _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`. If you want text messages see @Damien_The_Unbeliever answer

Answer (score 3):

Assuming SQL Server, the `SqlConnection` object has an [`InfoMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event that is raised for each of these sorts of messages (it also has a mode that can be enabled so that error messages are delivered via the same event, see [`FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.fireinfomessageeventonusererrors%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

You would access the text of these messages by extracting the `Message` property from the second argument passed to your event handler.

---

Something like:

```
    ...
    _con = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.DBconnStr)
    AddHandler _con.InfoMessage,Sub(sender,e)
                                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message)
                                End Sub
    queryStmt = "update ErrorLog set screen =  @Content where(ErrorLogID = 2)"
    ...
```

Comment: Now I realize I do need the responses as text messages. I would like to "translate them" into user readable info and present them in a messagebox.show. How do I implement this in code? I tried to read the link you have provided but I couldn't understand from that how to actually implement this. there is no code example there for me to reference.

Comment: This is a very bad decision. Maybe you detailed explain what you want to do? 
There are other more accurate design solutions..

Answer (score 2):

1. The ExecuteNonQuery() method of the ADO .NET SQLCommand returns rows affected count.
2. Stored procedures can return values through output parameters or through RETURN value parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Function insertScr(ByVal byte2insert As Byte()) As Boolean

    Dim _con As SqlConnection
    Dim queryStmt As String
    Dim _cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim param As SqlParameter
    Dim RowsAffected as Int

    Try

        _con = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.DBconnStr)
        queryStmt = "update ErrorLog set screen =  @Content where(ErrorLogID = 2)"
        _cmd = New SqlCommand(queryStmt, _con)
        param = _cmd.Parameters.Add("@Content", SqlDbType.VarBinary)

        param.Value = byte2insert

        _con.Open()
        RowsAffected  = _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        _con.Close()

        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception

        Return False

    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, I will explore this.